# How can I let my mom know when her soda drink goes on sale?

Tags: html, pdf, rss, feed, yahoo-pipes

I am trying to create the means for my mom to be notified when the Diet Rite drink, that she buys at Stater Bros, goes on sale.  My thinking is that I could create a Yahoo Pipe that takes in the weekly ad feed and filters for string Diet Rite.  The Yahoo Pipe is itself an RSS feed and, thus, I would deliver the Pipe to the Google Reader and thus my mom would know if Stater Bros is having a sale.

Seeing how the Stater Bros has a searchable PDF of their [weekly ad](http://www.staterbros.com/Images/PDFs/weekly.aspx), I thought it would be a simple matter of having Yahoo Pipes search through it.  However, Yahoo Pipes does not support PDF.

I then decided to pipe the PDF through an online PDF to HTML converter and feed that to `Fetch Page` module in Yahoo Pipes.  And in fact, the converter was [quite successful](http://www.pdfdownload.org/pdf2html/pdf2html.php?url=http://www.staterbros.com/Images/PDFs/weekly.aspx&images=yes), in that the resulting HTML preserved the text and I could search it and find what I needed.  However, it turns out that it spits its data out in frames - thus I can't use it.  I can't find any other online PDF to HTML converters.

Even if I was able to get the HTML of the PDF into Yahoo Pipes, I am not sure that would do any good, since Yahoo Pipes doesn't provide the means to search/filter HTML.  It mostly works on feeds.

So I am stuck.  Any ideas on how to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using it allready then you may want to look at Googles caching system ..

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.staterbros.com/Images/PDFs/weekly.aspx
```

It's not widely known outside SEO circles but the Googlebot does actually perform a crude PDF to HTML & text conversion. If you cannot wait for Google to convert the PDF file there are also a couple of free PHP scripts that can perform the same function.

Because there is no equivelent of 'Preg_match' for pipes you have to work backwards, 
by removing what is NOT what you are looking for.

The regex for the replace module looks something like this ...  **^(.+?)Diet Rite(.+?)$**
*Replace everything from the start of the string up to 'Diet Rite' with nothing
Then replace everything after 'Diet Rite' to the end of the string with nothing..*

Therefore if 'Diet Rite' exists on the page it will show up in the pipe and can be added to an RSS feed otherwise the pipe returns a blank.